# Improve site name in "What is meta?" Help Center article

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, help-center

Today, I posted a comment linking to the Help Center article [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) on Ask Different. I noticed that the Meta site was called 'Meta Ask Different', which is wrong; it's 'Ask Different Meta':

[image]

(The title of your browser tab will also show the real site name.)

It seems that that Help Center template starts with

> Meta [SITE NAME] is the part of the site

which only produces the right name for the trilogy: Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault (and arguably, Stack Exchange). It's wrong on all other 170+ sites in the network: [nobody uses the term "Meta Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H7bj.png). I'm wondering if it would be possible to rewrite the template so that it starts with

> [META SITE NAME] is the part of the site

That variable should be available 'somewhere' in the code; the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com) returns [related sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/related-site) with the word Meta in the right location (but, if applicable, suffixed with 'Stack Exchange'), e.g. 'Electrical Engineering Meta Stack Exchange'.